# Anchor Tag Not working

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I Have a two anchor tag for look like  below

```
<a href="www.exx.com" target="_blank">
            AnnualBudget</a>
```

When i click the above Anchor tag ,Its not gone correct URL(**For it's gone to Mydomainname/www.exx.com**). But the same time below anchor tag is working and go to correct url .

```
<a href="https://www.exx.com" target="_blank">
            AnnualBudget</a>
```

**Why www is not worked but https is worked** ? And How can i solve this issue ?

**Update** :

- **The url is entered from user in textbox .So how can i check it ?**

Comment: Try putting a "http://" in front.

Comment: The first example is missing the _scheme_ so is being interpreted as a link to a local resource see [*Url*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url) syntax on Wikipedia

Comment: The url is entered from user in textbox .So how can i check it ?

Comment: How about using string functions to compare? Please always [check and sanitize your user inputs](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting a "http://" in front.

I.e.

```
<a href="http://www.exx.com" target="_blank">AnnualBudget</a>
```

"www" is not a protocol/scheme. HTTPS or [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) are protocols.

Absolute URLs have to have a "scheme" in front, see [details about URLs on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator#Syntax).

Alternatively, this would also work:

```
<a href="//www.exx.com" target="_blank">AnnualBudget</a>
```

**Update 1:**

Since you comment that your input comes from the user, let me add this one:

[image]

(Although this refers to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), the same would be true for *all* user input).

**Update 2:**

To check the input for an absolute URL, do something like:

```
// Read from user input, e.g. (WebForms syntax!):
string my = MyTextBox.Text.Trim();

// Do some checking (this has be done much more thoroughly in real-life!)
if ( !my.StartsWith("http://") && !my.StartsWith("https://") )
{
    my = "http://" + my;
}

// Do something with "my", e.g. (again, WebForms syntax only):
MyHyperLink.NavigateUrl = my;
```

(Please note that I'm no MVC expert, the above pseudo-code uses WebForms syntax instead)

Comment: Nice one with the `//` prefix, wasn't aware of that! :)